# Concurrency design principles in practice

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I have a Results object which is written to by several threads concurrently. However, each thread has a specific purpose and owns certain fields, so that no data is actually modified by more than one thread. The consumer of this data will not try to read it until all of the writer threads are done writing it. Because I know this to be true, there is no synchronization on the data writes and reads.

There is a RunningState object associated with this Results object which serves to coordinate this work. All of its methods are synchronized. When a thread is done with its work on this Results object, it calls done() on the RunningState object, which does the following: decrements a counter, checks if the counter has gone to 0 (indicating that all writers are done), and if so, puts this object on a concurrent queue. That queue is consumed by a ResultsStore which reads all of the fields and stores data in the database. Before reading any data, the ResultsStore calls RunningState.finalizeResult(), which is an empty method whose sole purpose is to synchronize on the RunningState object, to ensure that writes from all of the threads are visible to the reader.

Here are my concerns:

1) I believe that this will work correctly, but I feel like I'm violating good design principles to not synchronize on the data modifications to an object that is shared by multiple threads. However, if I were to add synchronization and/or split things up so each thread only saw the data it was responsible for, it would complicate the code. Anyone who modifies this area had better understand what's going on in any case or they're likely to break something, so from a maintenance standpoint I think the simpler code with good comments explaining how it works is a better way to go.

2) The fact that I need to call this do-nothing method seems like an indication of wrong design. Is it?

Opinions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is sound, but it can be improved if you are using a true concurrent queue since a concurrent queue from the java.util.concurrent package already guarantees a happens before relationship between the thread putting an item into the queue, and the thread taking an item out, so this precludes needing to call finalizeResult() in the taking thread (so no need for that "do nothing" method call).

From java.util.concurrent package description:

> The methods of all classes in java.util.concurrent and its subpackages
>   extend these guarantees to higher-level synchronization. In
>   particular:
>
> - Actions in a thread prior to placing an object into any
>     concurrent collection happen-before actions subsequent to the access
>     or removal of that element from the collection in another thread.

The comments in another answer concerning using an AtomicInteger instead of synchronization are also wise (as using an AtomicInteger to do your thread counting will likely perform better than synchronization), just make sure to get the value of the count after the atomic decrement (e.g. decrementAndGet()) when comparing to 0 in order to avoid adding to the queue twice.

Comment: It ensures a happens-before between thread A putting that object in and thread B taking it out, but not between either of those and thread C modifying it.

Comment: @yshavit Per the design in question, there is already a relationship between thread A and the threads modifying the object (threads C, D, E...) per the synchronization done via invoking the done() method.

Comment: But that relationship is only established by thread A invoking `finalizeResult()` (if I understand it correctly, thread A doesn't call `done()`).

Comment: @yshavit ThreadA in the mentioned design is one of the threads doing the work, and it is putting the item on the queue as part of the implementation of done() (according to the question as written).

Comment: @yshavit is correct based on my understanding, except you mean thread B in your last comment. increment1, you're implying a sort of transitive visibility which I don't think is guaranteed.

Comment: @Dana If action 1 in thread A has a happens before relationship with action 2 in thread B, which in turn has a happens before relationship with action 3 in thread C; then there is a happens before relationship between action 1 in thread A and action 3 in thread C.  This is guaranteed.

Comment: @Dana This is noted in the Java spec here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.4.5  where it shows the transitive property via "if hb(x,y) and hb (y,z) then hb(x,z)".

Comment: @increment1 Oops, you're right -- I hadn't noticed that the thread which puts it on the concurrent queue is also one of the ones that called `done()`.

Comment: @increment1 Oh, I see now, thank you. That totally makes sense now that I think about it.  Yes I am using java.util.concurrent.

Answer (score 3):

This seems mostly right, if a bit fragile (if you change the thread-local nature of one field, for instance, you may forget to synchronize it and end up with hard-to-trace data races).

The big area of concern is in memory visibility; I don't think you've established it. The empty `finalizeResult()` method may be synchronized, but if the writer threads didn't also synchronize on whatever it synchronizes on (presumably `this`?), there's no happens-before relationship. Remember, synchronization isn't absolute -- you synchronize relative to other threads that are also synchronized *on the same object*. Your do-nothing method will indeed do nothing, not even ensure any memory barrier.

You somehow need to establish a happens-before relationship between each thread doing its writes, and the thread that eventually reads. One way to do this without synchronization is via a `volatile` variable, or an `AtomicInteger` (or other atomic classes).

For instance, each writer thread can invoke `counter.incrementAndGet(1)` on the object, and the reading thread can then check that `counter.get() == THE_CORRECT_VALUE`. There's a happens-before relationship between a volatile/atomic field being written and it being read, which gives you the needed visibility.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I believe happens-before is guaranteed by synchronization on the RunningState object. Writers call done() synchronized on that object when they are done, reader calls finalizeResult() synchronized on that object before reading.

Comment: @Dana Ah, sorry, I missed that. Your `done()` + `finalizeResult()` approach is basically the same as mine, except using `synchronized` instead of an `AtomicInteger`. As an alternate approach, you culd have each thread create its piece, publish that piece back to the "orchestration" thread in thread-safe way (e.g. a `Future<T>`), and have that orchestration thread put the pieces together into a `Result`.

Comment: +1.  Certainly `volatile` or `Atomic<whatever>` is more readable and maintainable in the future.

Comment: If the queue is concurrent then there is no need for the reading thread to read the counter in order to ensure a happens before relationship (concurrent queues already ensure the relationship).

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is indeed safe, but it also sounds, frankly, brittle and (as you note) maintenance could become an issue.  Without sample code, it's really hard to tell *what's* really easiest to understand, so an already subjective question becomes frankly unanswerable.  Could you ask a coworker for a code review?  (Particularly one that's likely to have to deal with this pattern.)  I'm going to trust you that this is indeed the simplest approach, but doing something like wrapping `synchronized` blocks around writes would increase safety now and in the future.  That said, you obviously know your code better than I do.

Comment: Regarding the comment in your point 2 about the end of a synchronization block (/monitor release) ensuring that all writes made by that thread are visible to all other threads, I do not believe that is the case according to the JMM, unless those other threads synchronize on the same monitor after its release (or some other activity ensures the happens-before relationship).  See section 17.4 of the Java 1.5 specification for reference.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  Upon re-reading the question, your point is absolutely correct, and upon re-reading my answer, it's clearly bullshit even if I *had* read the question correctly.  I'm not entirely sure what I was trying to say, but I'm pretty sure that it was wrong anyway.

Comment: That is the most contrite mea culpa I think I have ever read.  I have had the same feeling for a few of my answers in the past that I have revisted (not sure why they seemed like a good idea at the time).  In fairness, your answer was not that bad, just a minor technical mistake.

Comment: @increment1: I'll just chalk this one up to evidence that peer review and code reviews are helpful tools.